# Prob. 17, Chap. 5 in Baby Rudin: If $f(-1)=0=f(0)=f^\prime(0)$ and $f(1)=1$, then $f^{(3)}(x)\geq 0$ for some $x\in(-1,1)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, derivatives, taylor-expansion

Here is Prob. 17, Chap. 5 in the book *Principles of Mathematical Analysis* by Walter Rudin, 3rd edition:

> Suppose $f$ is a real, three times differentiable function on $[-1, 1]$, such that $$ f(-1)=0, \qquad f(0)=0, \qquad f(1)=1, \qquad f^\prime(0)=0.$$ Prove that $f^{(3)}(x)\geq 3$ for some $x \in (-1, 1)$.
>
> Note that equality holds for $\frac{1}{2} \left( x^2 + x^3 \right)$.
>
> *Hint:* Use Theorem 5.15, with $\alpha = 0$ and $\beta = \pm 1$, to show that there exist $s \in (0, 1)$ and $t \in (-1, 0)$ such that $$ f^{(3)}(s) + f^{(3)}(s) = 6.$$

Here is Theorem 5.15 in Baby Rudin, 3rd edition:

> Suppose $f$ is a real function on $[a, b]$, $n$ is a positive integer, $f^{(n-1)}$ is continuous on $[a, b]$, and $f^{(n)}(t)$ exists for every $t \in (a, b)$. Let $\alpha$, $\beta$ be distinct points of $[a, b]$, and define $$ P(t) = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{f^{(k)}(\alpha)}{k!} \left( t-\alpha \right)^k.$$ 
>   Then there exists a point $x$ between $\alpha$ and $\beta$ such that 
>   $$ f(\beta) = P(\beta) + \frac{f^{(n)}(x)}{n!} (\beta - \alpha )^n.$$

An Attempt:

> Applying the Taylor's theorem to $f$ first on $[0, 1]$ and then on $[-1, 0]$, we see that, for some points $s \in (0, 1)$ and $t \in (-1, 0)$, we have 
>   $$
> \begin{align}
> f(1) &= f(0) + f^\prime(0) + \frac{1}{2} f^{\prime\prime}(0) + \frac{1}{6} f^{(3)}(s), \\ 
> \mbox{ and } \qquad  f(-1) &= f(0) - f^\prime(0) + \frac{1}{2} f^{\prime\prime}(0) - \frac{1}{6} f^{(3)}(t).
> \end{align}
> $$
>   That is, 
>   $$
> \begin{align}
>  1 &= \frac{f^{\prime\prime}(0)}{2} + \frac{1}{6} f^{(3)}(s), \\
> \mbox{ and } \qquad 0 &= \frac{f^{\prime\prime}(0)}{2} - \frac{1}{6} f^{(3)}(t).
> \end{align}
> $$ 
>   Subtracting the second of the last two equations from the first one, we obtain 
>   $$ 1 = \frac{1}{6} \left( f^{(3)}(s) + f^{(3)}(t) \right),  $$
>   which in turn implies 
>   $$ f^{(3)}(s) + f^{(3)}(t) = 6. \tag{1} $$
>   Now if $f^{(3)}(x)$ were strictly less than $3$ for every $x \in [-1, 1]$, then we would also have $$ f^{(3)}(s) < 3 \ \mbox{ and } \ f^{(3)}(t) < 3, $$
>   which would then imply $$ f^{(3)}(s) + f^{(3)}(t) < 6, $$
>   thus contradicting (1) above.

Am I right?

> Now for $f(x) = \frac{1}{2} \left( x^2 + x^3 \right)$ for $x \in [-1, 1]$, we note that $$ f^\prime(x) = \frac{1}{2} \left( 2x + 3x^2 \right), \  f^{\prime\prime}(x) = \frac{1}{2} \left( 2 + 6x \right), \ \mbox{ and } \ f^{(3)}(x) = 3 \ \mbox{ for all } x \in [-1, 1].$$ 
>   Moreover, $$ f(-1)= 0, \ f(0)=0, \ f(1) = 1, \ f^\prime(0) = 0. $$

Is this proof the same as the one intended by Rudin?

Comment: Assuming Theorem 5.15 is Taylor's theorem with Cauchy remainder, your proof does look like the intended one.

Comment: @B.Mehta I've just editted my post to include Theorem 5.15 in Baby Rudin.

Comment: Yes, I think your proof is the same as the intended one.

Comment: @B.Mehta which books do you learn your first courses in analysis, topology, and functional analysis over there at Trinity College? Does Trinity College Math Dept offer any videos, notes, exams and assignments with solutions for these courses on the Internet?

Comment: Almost all of our courses don't use textbooks, and most lecture notes are not published online.  That said, you can find a list of recommended books  [here](https://www.maths.cam.ac.uk/undergrad/course/schedules.pdf) for the relevant courses, past papers can be found [here](https://www.maths.cam.ac.uk/undergrad/pastpapers), without solutions, and question sheets are [here](https://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/study/), again without solutions. Finally I'd recommend Timothy Gowers' [blog](https://gowers.wordpress.com/category/cambridge-teaching/ia-analysis/), which has material from the analysis course.

Comment: You can use argument by contradiction to prove and it is pretty simple.